# Windows phone 8.1 stream media in background

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, background-task, background-audio

Can we stream media in the background using the MediaPlayer class in windows phone 8.1?

I dont use mediaelement to manually create a player to stream media. Can this be used to implement, background audio in Windows phone 8.1

Here's the difference,
The sample code what is online from MSDN uses MediaPlayer and it does not stream.

If you want to stream we have to use MediaElement is what my understanding is.

Any ideas?